# computing cost of np.random.uniform vs np.random.beta

Tags: python, memory, random, time

I have an algorithm that uses np.random.uniform I would like to switch to np.random.beta and/or np.random.gamma to improve the efficiency of an approximation. Since the algorithm is already quite time consuming (~8hours) and memory intensive (5 GB per thread) I wanted to check if there was any information on how much this would cost me before I tried a run.

Since it is called inside a loop, should I assume it is not going to change the memory requirements?

What is the difference in run time?

Comment: Do you know how many times that function is called in one run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test it using ipython:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: %timeit np.random.random(1000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.25 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.random.beta(0.5, 0.5, 1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.3 µs per loop
```

This would imply a factor of 5, but it appears to depend on the parameters of beta.

Nevertheless, before drawing any conclusions, you should be sure that the random number generation is the time-limiting factor for your algorithm. Run a profiler to find out where your real bottlenecks are.